# not able to access the values from model passed to the view in an asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Below is the code snippet for the controller

```
public ActionResult ListTeacher()
        {
            List<Teacher> Teachers = new List<Teacher>();
            TeacherDataController controller = new TeacherDataController();
            Teachers = controller.ListTeachers();

            return View(Teachers);

        }
```

but i cannot access the values from the model

Comment: Are you really calling a controller Action? And, what is the Model type declared in the View?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.